# what is the best way to cite different homepage from the same cooperation website?

Tags: biblatex

what is the best way to cite different homepage from the same cooperation website? also with the same author and different  url and title?

For example, Oracle or Google. For citation I am using biblatex with @misc. misc has not an attribute like "page" in @article
For example:
url 1: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/index.html
url 2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/zend/index.html

Comment: Why not use `@online`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of do it in BibTeX is with a `@misc` entry:

```
@misc{Oracle1,
  title = {{Oracle} Application Development Framework (ADF) Articles},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/index.html}},
  note = {Accessed: 2015-01-31}
}

@misc{Oracle2,
  title = {{Oracle} Zend Server},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/zend/index.html}},
  note = {Accessed: 2015-01-31}
}
```

**EDIT**

A thanks to [Sigur](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14757/sigur) for this note:

Don't forget to load `\usepackage{url}`.

**EDIT 2**

A simple way of do it in BibLaTeX (because the tag is BibLaTeX, as noted by [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)) is with a `@online` entry:

```
@online{Oracle1,
  title = {{Oracle} Application Development Framework (ADF) Articles},
  url{http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/index.html},
  note = {Accessed: 2015-01-31}
}

@online{Oracle2,
  title = {{Oracle} Zend Server},
  url{http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/zend/index.html},
  note = {Accessed: 2015-01-31}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to load `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: The question is tagged as "biblatex" and there it is better to put urls in the url-field to avoid problems with underscores and similar symbols (and I would use the @online type).

Comment: Ok @ulrike-fischer, I edit now.